# Change name of sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel

Can you tell me how to change the name of Excel sheet names:
Eg: "Sheet1" - "MyNewSheet" using VB code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use VB.NET or VBA (e. g. do you develop a macro within the excel application?)

The code Itself is simple:
Sheet.Name = "Your Name"
Too long names are a problem.
ALso, I would check the name before writing it - if the name is already in the Workbook, it will cause an error.

```
Private Sub SetName(name as string)

Dim ActSheet As Worksheet

Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet

Dim NameIsOk as Boolean

NameIsOk = true

dim i as Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = name then
       NameIsOk = false
    End If
Next

If NameIsOk Then
    ActSheet = name
End if
End Sub
```

This code sets the name of the worksheet to the desired name, but ONLY if the sheet name is not found in the current Workbook

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using Sub test()
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "New Sheet"
End Sub but this could be a good help in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Could you kindly accept the answer?
The problem with you code is the insecurity with already existing names. I ran multiple times into this fallacy, especially if you run your macro multiple times.